# No YouTube ads when using chrome incognito window on iphone

Tags: google-chrome, browser, youtube, ads, yt

on my iphone when I use youtube through Google Chrome incognito window there are no ads at all can anyone explain why is that? Thank you.

Comment: from where ? did you deny the use of cookies (GDPR applies in Europe) ? are you logged in ?

Comment: From Europe, when GDPR pop up appears I click Accept all and I am not logged in.

Comment: Even if i log in there are no ads.